# location.href in jquery ajax success is not triggered

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am using jquery's $.ajax to send json data as post request to my internal server. I am able to get response, but on success function, while console.log works but not the immediate line location.href='/users'; even if I have location.href alone in the success, it isn't been triggered. Below is my code sample

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
       function submitData() {
           var payload = {
               'fullname': $('#fullname').val(),
               'username': $('#username').val(),
               'email': $('#email').val(),
               'password': $('#password').val(),
           };

           var onSuccess = function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
               console.log(jqXHR.status);
               location.href= "/thankyou.html";
           };


           $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                async: false,
                url: '/users',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: JSON.stringify(payload),
                success: onSuccess,
            });
        }
</script>
```

I have also tried window.location, window.location.href, window.location.assign(), none seems to work in the above code. But strangely, when I define a complete callback for ajax and alert something, location.href on success works rarely (but not everytime). I have also looked through similar questions and tried those answers, but doesn't seems to fix this. Having async=true, gets an Broken Pipe error on my flask server.

Comment: should it be `../users` ?

Comment: No, there is no problem with url, since my data is received by server and gets created there and also sends an 201 response code, also at times, location.href works rarely with same /users url. Definitely that is not a problem.

Comment: what strange logic.  You will POST to /users using ajax and then when it is done you will ignore the data in the response and then redirect to the same /users.  Why bother coming back to JS? Redirect from the POST.

Comment: I would set async to true or omit that line as it's the default. This can mess with events on success I think.

Comment: try `location.replace('/users');` ?

Comment: @user2310289 now I have edited the code, replaced '/users' with /thankyou.html. Now lets ignore what the logic is, still location.href isn't working.

Comment: @Papa on omitting async and letting it default makes it True and so I am facing the broken pipe error as mentioned in my question and that did not help me.

Comment: Just a thought, try `return false` after the `window.location.href= "/thankyou.html";`

Comment: What version of jquery?

Comment: @Papa am using Jquery 1.4.0 directly from google's CDN http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.0/jquery.min.js

Comment: Just curious, if you're getting a broken pipe error, doesn't that mean your data call is broken? What do you return in the response?

Comment: Fixed. replacing input type from submit to button in my html helped. Thanks to @vivek parekh

Comment: you should have posted your rest of the code to save every one's time! cause it seems every one else was looking under the hood while actual problem was that your car had flat tyre

Comment: @Barewithme It quite actually a large file, and so posting rest of the code would be really bad. The problem was I myself did not think there would be a problem with html code and I thought it is a problem with Javascript and so avoided the html part. Thank you and sorry for time consuming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to call it this way:

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            async: false,
            url: '/users',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: JSON.stringify(payload),
            success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
                console.log(jqXHR.status);
                window.location.href= "/thankyou.html";
            }
        });
```

Also your code for the ajax call has got a `,` at `success:` event which is an error.

Comment: Tried this, console.log works, but not the location.

Comment: Is it a submit button that you are using? On click of which you are calling this function `submitData()`?

Comment: Oh, yes. I was using submit, and now changed to input type to button and works :-) Thank you. But why is that?

Comment: Please follow this [**link here**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12714857/ajax-call-doesnt-work-when-a-submit-button-is-used)

And check mark the answer. :)

Comment: Hey thanks for the above link, I understood what was happening. I really wanted to mark the answer, but it is your comment that holds the answer right? If I cannot mark the comment, then I will mark this answer. Thank You :-)

Comment: Well, Yes it is the comment actually, that solved the question. ;-)

Anyways, Thank you.! :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
  $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/users',
        data: JSON.stringify(payload),
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        cache: false,
        timeout: 100000,
        success: function (response) {
            location.href= "/thankyou.html";
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#cateInfo').submit(function(event){
 event.preventDefault();
 var $form = $(this);
 $.ajax({
 type: 'POST',
 url: $form.attr('action'),
 data: $form.serialize(),
 success: function(data) {
     location.href= "/admin/list-category";
 },
 error: function(error) {
    alert(error);
 }
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove onSuccess function and put redirect inside success itself. OR check if u have any errors using firebug console so that your success is not triggered at all.

Comment: then server side response needs to be checked. put a alert in success and see.