# jquery ajax dosen't work in asp.net mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

i have a project which is using bootstrap Modal as login partial view, but i want have a asynchronization solution to do validation of user login, so via `jquery.post` to pass data to action and, but i found there `jquery.post` sucess done but no response from action.

View:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">    
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Login </h4>
            </div>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="modal-body" id="signinForm">
                    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Login", "Account", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "signinForm" }, new { @id = "targetForm" }))
                    {    
                        // Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "signinForm" });

                        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "Account creation was unsuccessful. Please correct the errors and try again.")
                        <div id="errorresult"></div>
                        <div class="control-group">
                            <label class="control-label" for="inputEmail">User Name</label>
                            <div class="controls">
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName, new { @name = "inputUser", @class = "form-control", @id = "inputUser", @placeholder = "User Name" })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName)
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="control-group">
                            <label class="control-label" for="inputPassword">Password</label>
                            <div class="controls">
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Password, new { @name = "inputPassword", @class = "form-control", @id = "inputPassword", @placeholder = "Password", @type = "password" })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password)
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="control-group">
                            <div class="controls">
                                <label class="checkbox">
                                    Remember me @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.RememberMe, new {@id="rememberMe"})
                                    <span class="span9">@Html.ActionLink("Register", "Register", "Account")   </span>
                                </label>
                                <button type="submit" id="submit_btn" class="btn btn-primary">sign in</button>

                            </div>
                        </div>                            
                    }    
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$('#submit_btn').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var targetForm = $('#targetForm').serialize();
       var newtargetForm= targetForm.replace(/&/g, "?");
        $.post("@Url.Action("AjaxLogin", "Account")?"+ newtargetForm, {
            userName: $('#targetForm #inputUser').val(),
            passWord: $('#targetForm #inputPassword').val(),
            rememberMe:$('#targetForm #rememberMe').is(':checked')
        }, function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
            /*optional stuff to do after success */
            console.log(textStatus);
        })    
    })
```

My Action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AjaxLogin(string UserName, string Password, bool RememberMe)
{
   if (ModelState.IsValid)
   {
       if (Membership.ValidateUser(UserName,Password))
       {
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(UserName, RememberMe);
            return RedirectToAction("BlogPost","Blog");
       }
   }
   return PartialView("Login");
}
```

from my understanding, route rule of asp.net mvc should work, but it didn't.

Comment: what is your browser console saying ?

Comment: console.log(textStatus); saying "success"

Comment: I would fire up FireBug and see what comes up. I don't think you can/should mix jQuery and MVC Ajax like that. I haven't used the MS Ajax stuff, but it looks like they're both trying to simultaneously handle the same submit.

Comment: how is the result you got?

Answer (score 0):

**Problem:**

`type="submit"` causes the web browser to submit the form via a postback (because your `method` attribute is set to "POST"), which causes the page to refresh. When this happens, all javascript on the page terminates because you are effectively going to a different page or reloading the current one.

Stolen from [Ajax call doesn't work when a submit button is used](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12714885/2668547)

**Solution:**

Change the 
`<button type="submit" id="submit_btn">` 
 to 
`<button type="button" id="submit_btn">`

And keep rest of the code as it is.

Comment: I think there isnt issue with it as he have used `event.preventDefault();`

Comment: yes, event.preventDefault() can ignore submit action